# trying to fetch the Matching values using $or operator in "mongodb" but not getting data

Tags: php, mongodb

I am new in mengodb : trying to fetch the Matching values using $or operator but not getting data

```
global $db;

$data = $db->newsfeed->find({$or: [{'link': $data['link']},{'title': $data['title']} ]}).pretty(); 

echo "<pre>";print_r($data);exit;

But when i execute the query in mongodb database it work 

db.newsfeed.find({
    $or: 
    [{'link': 'link go here'},{'title': 'som data to search'} ]
    }).pretty();
```

Comment: Please post the command and data that you inserted into the database

Answer (score 0):

used to check or condition in megento

$where  = array('$or' => array(array("postLink" => $data['link']), array("title" => $data['title'])));
$count = $db->newsfeed->count($where);

Working perfectly